# OpenCV detect towel margins

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

What would be the best method (using python and OpenCV) of finding the lowest corner ( not edge ) of towel in this images?
Also, the towel color can be different, but the background color will be always the same.

[image: towel]

And I need this corner ( the lowest "real" towel corner ):
[image: expected result]

Comment: you mean 'edges' of the towel?

Comment: what does it mean? what you want to do explain your question

Comment: Hi, I need to get the coordinates ( x,y) of the lowest corner ( not edge, corner )

Answer (score 6):

Since you have approximately two distinct colors in the image (one each for foreground and background) you could convert your image to HSV color space and visualize each of the individual channels.

**Code:**

```
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop'
filename = 'towel.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename))    
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)     #--- convert to HSV
cv2.imshow('hsv.jpg', hsv)
h = hsv[:,:,0]
cv2.imshow('h.jpg', h)                         #--- visualize the hue channel
```

[image]

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(h, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh)                  #--- apply Otsu threshold on hue channel
```

[image]

Notice that white blob in the center of the towel, it has to be removed. For that purpose I have used morphological opening.

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(25, 25))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.imshow('fin', cv2.bitwise_not(opening))
```

[image]

### EDIT

OpenCV provides the functionality to find top, bottom, right-most and left-most corners for a given contour. I obtained the contour of the final resulting image and found the four extreme points.

**Code:**

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cv2.bitwise_not(opening), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)                #--- finding contours
cnt = contours[0]                                 #--- since there is only one contour present

leftmost = tuple(cnt[cnt[:,:,0].argmin()][0])
rightmost = tuple(cnt[cnt[:,:,0].argmax()][0])
topmost = tuple(cnt[cnt[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
bottommost = tuple(cnt[cnt[:,:,1].argmax()][0])

print('The extreme points are leftmost: {}, rightmost: {}, topmost: {} and bottommost: {}'.format(leftmost, rightmost, topmost, bottommost))

The extreme points are leftmost: (32, 336), rightmost: (807, 439), topmost: (459, 12) and bottommost: (699, 743)
```

I have also marked the extreme points on a copy of the original image:

```
img2 = img.copy()
cv2.circle(img2, leftmost, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)    #-- leftmost
cv2.circle(img2, rightmost, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)    #-- rightmost
cv2.circle(img2, topmost, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)    #-- topmost
cv2.circle(img2, bottommost, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)    #-- bottommost
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. But how can I get the lowest corner ( not edge, corner ) coordinates ( x,y ) ?

Comment: @Daniel If this answers your question, consider accepting it to help other users in the future!

Comment: Hi, the answers is almost perfect.  It's a perfect start, but I somehow need the find the 90 degrees corners, not the bottom most points

Comment: @Daniel Can you post an image with the expected marking?

Comment: @JeruLuke I've updated the question with another picture, with the expected result. I need to find the real corner ( 90 degrees ) down there

Comment: @Daniel I get it now! Need to come up with something custom for that !!

Comment: @JeruLuke I'm also working now some tests based on your code - the start you gave me is great.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is edge detection algorithm.

Use the below code from the following [Link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('Your towel image.jpg',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canny edge detector. For to detect the corner of the image.I have given you the link of 2 sources below.

[Source1](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/canny-edge-detector-using-python--cms-30095)

[Source2](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html)

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('boat.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(im,25,255,L2gradient=False)
plt.imshow(edges,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```